# web scraping and data processing in java

Tags: java, html, regex, web-scraping, data-processing

I am writing a web scraper program to extract stock quotes from yahoo finance,google finance or nasdaq. I can get the html element containing the stock prices but I only need the dollar value from the result. For example the sample output looks like the image below:
[image]

I am using an image here because when I posted the actual html, only the dollar amounts (the desired results) showed up, the html entities and tags vanished.
Here is my code
 [image]
 I am not very familiar with regEx but I tried it but no luck. How can I extract only the dollar amount from the output?

Comment: If you're parsing HTML, why not use a parser such as JSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `java.util.regex.Matcher` and `java.util.regex.Pattern`:

```
String pattern = "<td>\\$&.+;(\\d{1,4}\\.\\d{2})&";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine);

if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Price: $" + m.group(1) );
}
```

Result:

> Price: $130.27 ...

Example:

http://ideone.com/fWgvL5#stdout

Comment: continuing with my incomplete comment above, I was able to get the example  above to work but I'm rather getting less than 100 results out of a multiple page list, do you think it might be a regex problem? I also made this change \\d{2} ==> \\d{1,4} for precision. I think I might be getting the entire list but netbeans is just printing partial list. Either way, how do I vote so you can get credits? I am a newbie here, please have mercy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3422517, I'm uncertain about why you might only be getting a partial output. Does the output stop consistently in the same place each time? As for how voting works, if you feel your question was appropriately answered you can mark it as  `correct` by clicking the checkmark underneath the vote count. Once you gain enough reputation you can then also upvote or downvote questions and answers. Lastly, welcome to stackoverflow! :)

Comment: @user3422517 is there any reason you're not using a DOM parser like [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org)?

That's by far more efficient when compared to regexp. It is well documented that regular expressions are a bad idea for web scrapping tasks.

Answer (score -1):

str_replace will work.

It will look like

```
$string = str_replace('&nbsp;</td><td>.*?</td>','&nbsp;</td>', $string);
```

The `.*?` will match the value in between the tags that do not have `&nbsp;` in them with the above code. Find the correct deliminator. `.*? or .*(?)` etc

The above code will then delete every tag that is `<td>number</td>`while keeping every `<td>$&nbsp;number&nbsp;</td>`

Where did you find how to scrape live finance data? Is that in an xml feed somewhere?

Comment: I think you were using a scripting language, I might use that in the future but now I'm working with java application. You can find real time trades at nasdaq.com, you just need to find what trading data interests you. You can find pre-market, real-time, and after-market in a table format.